# Drag & Drop not working with Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, drag-and-drop, selenium-chromedriver

I want to implement a simple drag and drop with selenium python. I am using Chrome WebDriver and below is my code. Nothing happens. Any help is highly apprecited.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common import exceptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://html5demos.com/drag")
dragElement=driver.find_element_by_id("one")
dropElement=driver.find_element_by_id("bin")

action_chains = ActionChains(driver)
action_chains.drag_and_drop(dragElement, dropElement).perform()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use a workaround I've mentioned above at the moment.
I've also wrapped it up as a Python package, so it would be easy to use.

You can install the package with `pip install seletools`

An example of usage is [here](https://pypi.org/project/seletools/).

Answer (score 1):

Selenium Drag & Drop functionality is straightforward and you need to make usage of **Selenium ActionChains**.

*ActionChains are a way to automate low level interactions such as mouse movements, mouse button actions, key press, and context menu interactions. This is useful for doing more complex actions like hover over and drag and drop.*

Refer to [documentation](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html):

In your specific case you need to identify the source and the target of the action (the image and one of the boxes) and after call the `drag_and_drop` function.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://html5demos.com/drag")
source_element = driver.find_element_by_id('bin')
dest_element = driver.find_element_by_id('two')
ActionChains(driver).drag_and_drop(source_element, dest_element).perform()
```

Comment: Hi @aberna, I tried that.... it doesnt work :( It only highlights the element but never really drags it. I ended up implementing a custom JS which takes care of drag and drop.

Comment: @prgrmr do you happen to have this solution anywhere uploaded? or would u mind answering your own question? I have exactly the same issue with you.

Comment: It dint work with selenium.. I imported jquery, used its drag and drop :/

Answer (score 1):

You can execute this script as the fast fix at the moment (works well for me on both Chrome and Firefox).
https://gist.github.com/druska/624501b7209a74040175#file-native_js_drag_and_drop_helper-js

What I did is just added **simulateDragDrop(arguments[0], arguments[1])**:

```
function simulateDragDrop(sourceNode, destinationNode) {
    var EVENT_TYPES = {
        DRAG_END: 'dragend',
        DRAG_START: 'dragstart',
        DROP: 'drop'
    }

    function createCustomEvent(type) {
        var event = new CustomEvent("CustomEvent")
        event.initCustomEvent(type, true, true, null)
        event.dataTransfer = {
            data: {
            },
            setData: function(type, val) {
                this.data[type] = val
            },
            getData: function(type) {
                return this.data[type]
            }
        }
        return event
    }

    function dispatchEvent(node, type, event) {
        if (node.dispatchEvent) {
            return node.dispatchEvent(event)
        }
        if (node.fireEvent) {
            return node.fireEvent("on" + type, event)
        }
    }

    var event = createCustomEvent(EVENT_TYPES.DRAG_START)
    dispatchEvent(sourceNode, EVENT_TYPES.DRAG_START, event)

    var dropEvent = createCustomEvent(EVENT_TYPES.DROP)
    dropEvent.dataTransfer = event.dataTransfer
    dispatchEvent(destinationNode, EVENT_TYPES.DROP, dropEvent)

    var dragEndEvent = createCustomEvent(EVENT_TYPES.DRAG_END)
    dragEndEvent.dataTransfer = event.dataTransfer
    dispatchEvent(sourceNode, EVENT_TYPES.DRAG_END, dragEndEvent)
}

simulateDragDrop(arguments[0], arguments[1]);
```

I saved this one as **drag_and_drop.js** file in **scripts** folder of my project's directory.
Then I used next code in my tests:

```
DRAGGABLE_SELECTOR = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[draggable]")
DROPPABLE_SELECTOR = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".ReactCollapse--content > div > div > div > div > div > div[id]")
draggable = self.app.wd.find_element(*DRAGGABLE_SELECTOR)
droppable = self.app.wd.find_element(*DROPPABLE_SELECTOR)
f = open("scripts/drag_and_drop.js",  "r")
javascript = f.read()
f.close()
wd.execute_script(javascript, draggable, droppable)
```

One more thing: this script accepts elements found by **CSS selectors** only (because it's a JQuery script)!